# Shortcut Assign Primary Key while create table

Tags: mysql

What is the right way to assign primary key with shortcut query while creating table?

Here is the example how my shortcut it is:

```
create table booking_product (
`id` int(10) not null constraint `booking_product_id` primary key auto_increment ,
`bookingId` int(10) not null,
`serviceId` int(10) not null,
`date` date not null,
`price` decimal(30,15) not null,
`qty` int(1) not null,
`currencyId` int(10) not null,
`total` decimal(30,15) not null,
`roomInclusion` text null default null,

foreign key booking_product(bookingId) references booking(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
foreign key booking_product(serviceId) references service(id) on update cascade on delete set null,
foreign key booking_product(currencyId) references currency(id) on update cascade on delete set null
) engine = InnoDB;
```

- notice on line 2 I tried to assign primary key, but this query is wrong and produce error. If I try to only use `id int(10) not null  primary key auto_increment ,` I get error: `Duplicate key name 'booking_product'`

Comment: You do realize that `int(10)` will ***not*** limit the values to 10 digits?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is that mean `int(10)` the max value is not `9.999.999.999`?

Comment: No, it only means that the display width of integer is 10 , it doesnt restrict the range of values. The numeric range of any signed INT including INT(10), INT(5) or any other INT(n) is:
-2,147,483,648 ... 2,147,483,647, which is 10 digits at most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `constraint booking_product_id`, you don't get errors about `Duplicate key name 'booking_product'` because the SQL parser stops at the first error.

Drop `constraint booking_product_id` and use

```
foreign key bookingId_fk(bookingId) references booking(id)
    on update cascade
    on delete cascade,
foreign key serviceId_fk(serviceId) references service(id)
    on update cascade
    on delete set null,
foreign key currencyId_fk(currencyId) references currency(id)
    on update cascade
    on delete set null
```

Comment: Yes, i get error `duplicate key same`. It seems because before this i already create table name `booking_product` and then drop that table. But i didn't understand. if i drop the table isn't it should be also delete the primary key from that dropped table?

Comment: i try your code `DROP CONSTRAINT `booking_product_id`;` it give me this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT `booking_product_id`' at line 1`

Comment: Oh, i understand. The error is not coming from `primary key`. But from the foreign key. e.g. `currencyId_fk(currencyId)` the string after `()` i thinks that a table name. So it is the key name instead. My Bad @_@.

Comment: Right! Syntax is `foreign key [KeyName]([Columns]) references [OtherTable]([OtherColumns])`.

Answer (score 1):

I know you picked an answer but when I simplified just your create statement to the code below I got it to work.  Now with the added 'drop constraint' request by Oswald you might have everything you want:

```
create table booking_product (
id int(10) not null auto_increment,
PRIMARY KEY(id),  <<<<< this worked for me...
bookingId int(10) not null,
serviceId int(10) not null,
date date not null,
price decimal(30,15) not null,
qty int(1) not null,
currencyId int(10) not null,
total decimal(30,15) not null,
roomInclusion text null default null)
```

Again I am only approaching the question from what you asked which was assigning a primary.

Hope this helps.